# How can I create all pairwise combinations of multiple columns in a Pyspark Dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Consider the following Pyspark dataframe

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | D | G |
| B | E | H |
| C | F | I |

How can I create the following dataframe which has all pairwise combinations of all the columns?

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col1_Col2_cross | Col1_Col3_cross | Col2_Col3_cross |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | D | G | A,D | A,G | D,G |
| B | E | H | B,E | B,H | E,H |
| C | F | I | C,F | C,I | F,I |

Comment: Does it need to work for any amount of columns, or only 3?

Comment: Any amount of columns. I actually have about ~30 columns, but just showed 3 here to simplify the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate column combinations using `itertools`:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import itertools

df2 = df.select(
    '*', 
    *[F.concat_ws(',', x[0], x[1]).alias(x[0] + '_' + x[1] + '_cross') 
      for x in itertools.combinations(df.columns, 2)]
)

df2.show()
+----+----+----+---------------+---------------+---------------+
|Col1|Col2|Col3|Col1_Col2_cross|Col1_Col3_cross|Col2_Col3_cross|
+----+----+----+---------------+---------------+---------------+
|   A|   D|   G|            A,D|            A,G|            D,G|
|   B|   E|   H|            B,E|            B,H|            E,H|
|   C|   F|   I|            C,F|            C,I|            F,I|
+----+----+----+---------------+---------------+---------------+
```